# filter elements from list from another list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to filter elements by filtering from another list using python, but some elements are missing. below is my code

```
input_list = [('firstname', 'string'), ('middlename', 'string'), ('lastname', 'string'), ('age', 'string'), ('gender', 'string'), ('salary', 'int'), ('amount', 'double'), ('amount1', 'decimal(10,2)')]

filter_list = ['int','bigint','decimal']

output_list =  [ c for c,d in input_list if d in filter_list]
```

I am getting output as
output_list = ['salary']

but expecting output_list = ['salary','amount1']
missing decimal related values, any suggestions?

Comment: `decimal(10,2)` isn't in the `filter_list`, you need to check if any of the filter list is a prefix to `d`

Comment: yes only decimal is there, want to get those records also

Answer (score 0):

`d in filter_list` uses equality, but it seems you just want to check the prefix.

`output_list = [c for c, d in input_list if any(d.startswith(p) for p in filter_list)]` should do what you want.

Comment: I suggest you read the `startswith` documentation.

Comment: Huh ? I did that and don't see the issue. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: You do stuff it can do for you. Note the sentence about the tuple.